# how to implement fragment in android

Tags: android

am currently messing around with DialogFragment to learn to use it. I assumed that compared to `onCreateView()`, `onCreate()` can do this:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    testTextView.setText("SUCCESS!"); //ERROR HERE
}
```

But I am wrong. Not sure why its not working. The error goes away when I comment out `testTextView.setText("Success!");` The error is a `NullPointerException`, and then it just flags line 39 which is where the offending line of code is. Any clarifications much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

where you initalzed testTextView. ? you should do that.........

and also as per fragment life cycle

```
onAttach(Activity)-->onCreate(Bundle) -->onCreateView(LayoutInflater, ViewGroup, Bundle)->onActivityCreated(Bundle)-->onStart()
```

so you should handle this work either in onCreateView or after this...

http://android-developers.blogspot.in/2012/05/using-dialogfragments.html

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    if (container == null) {
        return null;
    }
    return (LinearLayout)inflater.inflate(R.layout.your_fragmentlayout_file, container, false);
}



@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstance)
{
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstance);
    TextView testTextView = (TextView)getActivity().findViewById(R.id.your_textview_id);
    testTextView.setText("SUCCESS!");
}
```